# What does Cookie Monster say in this song?

Tags: listening

I like this song ["Sesame Street: Smarter, Stronger, Kinder Song"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hviFeDR8DqQ).

but I can't understand [what Cookie Monster and the girl sing from 0:10 to 0:16](https://youtu.be/hviFeDR8DqQ?t=10s).

Please help me.

I hear

> ***the girl: Kind at home when you play***
>
> ***Cookie Monster: Try the cherry get carry everyday***

I think that's meaningless and wrong.

Comment: ... Most of what Cookie Monster says isn't grammatical English... His most famous quote is "me like cookie".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it goes like this

> Rosita: Kind at home **and** when you play
>   Cookie Monster: Try **some sharing** and **caring** everyday

Her name is Rosita and she has a slight accent. Cookie monster does sound like he is saying **ch** instead of **sh**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once you told me correct, I can hear it. Very happy. Thanks again.